# uwsgi 1.0.4 logging File handle not release

Tags: linux, django, uwsgi

i have an application for High requests count for django(1.3.1)+uwsgi(1.0.4), when i configure uwsgi with xml format:  ”`<log-maxsize>51200000</log-maxsize>`“, log file will cut to small size automatic`uwsgi.log.1485843562  uwsgi.log.1487389022  uwsgi.log.1488980345  uwsgi.log.1490664169`,but all file's handle not released anyway, so disk was used as 100% cannot save another file anymore.